# Xelatex pdf not built properly in editorial manager but works fine in laptop. Kindly help

Tags: tamil

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018/W32TeX)
(preloaded format=pdflatex 2018.7.12) 19 MAY 2020 05:35
entering extended mode
restricted \write18 enabled.
%&-line parsing enabled.
**manuscriptfinal2.tex
(./ManuscriptFinal2.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-04-01> patch level 5
LaTeX Warning: File `example.eps' already exists on the system.
Not generating it from this source.
(c:/TeXLive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fix-cm.sty
Package: fix-cm 2015/01/14 v1.1t fixes to LaTeX
(c:/TeXLive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.def
File: ts1enc.def 2001/06/05 v3.0e (jk/car/fm) Standard LaTeX file
Now handling font encoding TS1 ...
... processing UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding TS1
(c:/TeXLive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.dfu
File: ts1enc.dfu 2018/04/05 v1.2c UTF-8 support for inputenc
defining Unicode char U+00A2 (decimal 162)
defining Unicode char U+00A3 (decimal 163)
defining Unicode char U+00A4 (decimal 164)
defining Unicode char U+00A5 (decimal 165)
defining Unicode char U+00A6 (decimal 166)
defining Unicode char U+00A7 (decimal 167)
defining Unicode char U+00A8 (decimal 168)
defining Unicode char U+00A9 (decimal 169)
defining Unicode char U+00AA (decimal 170)
defining Unicode char U+00AC (decimal 172)
defining Unicode char U+00AE (decimal 174)
defining Unicode char U+00AF (decimal 175)
defining Unicode char U+00B0 (decimal 176)
defining Unicode char U+00B1 (decimal 177)
defining Unicode char U+00B2 (decimal 178)
defining Unicode char U+00B3 (decimal 179)
defining Unicode char U+00B4 (decimal 180)
defining Unicode char U+00B5 (decimal 181)

defining Unicode char U+266A (decimal 9834)
defining Unicode char U+FEFF (decimal 65279)
))) (./svjour3.cls
Document Class: svjour3 2007/05/08 v3.2
LaTeX document class for Springer journals
(c:/TeXLive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fleqn.clo
File: fleqn.clo 2016/12/29 v1.2a Standard LaTeX option (flush left
equations)
\mathindent=\dimen102
Applying: [2015/01/01] Make \[ robust on input line 50.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 51.
Already applied: [0000/00/00] Make \[ robust on input line 62.
Applying: [2015/01/01] Make \] robust on input line 74.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 75.
Already applied: [0000/00/00] Make \] robust on input line 83.
)
Class Springer-SVJour3 Info: extra/valid Springer sub-package (-> *.clo)
(Springer-SVJour3) not found in option list of \documentclass
(Springer-SVJour3) - autoactivating "global" style.
(./svglov3.clo
File: svglov3.clo 2009/12/18 v3.2 style option for standardised journals
SVJour Class option: svglov3.clo for standardised journals
)
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math symbol \Gamma on input line 147.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math symbol \Delta on input line 148.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math symbol \Theta on input line 149.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math symbol \Lambda on input line 150.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math symbol \Xi on input line 151.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math symbol \Pi on input line 152.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math symbol \Sigma on input line 153.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math symbol \Upsilon on input line 154.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math symbol \Phi on input line 155.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math symbol \Psi on input line 156.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math symbol \Omega on input line 157.
\logodepth=\dimen103
\headerboxheight=\dimen104
\betweenumberspace=\dimen105
\aftertext=\dimen106
\headlineindent=\dimen107
\c@inst=\count80
\c@auth=\count81
\instindent=\dimen108
\authrun=\box26
\authorrunning=\toks14
\titrun=\box27
\titlerunning=\toks15
\combirun=\box28
\c@lastpage=\count82
\rubricwidth=\dimen109
\c@section=\count83
\c@subsection=\count84
\c@subsubsection=\count85
\c@paragraph=\count86
\c@subparagraph=\count87
\spthmsep=\dimen110
\c@theorem=\count88
\c@case=\count89
\c@conjecture=\count90
\c@corollary=\count91
\c@definition=\count92
\c@example=\count93
\c@exercise=\count94
\c@lemma=\count95
\c@note=\count96
\pgf@xa=\dimen121
\pgf@ya=\dimen122
\pgf@xb=\dimen123
\pgf@yb=\dimen124
\pgf@xc=\dimen125
\pgf@yc=\dimen126
\w@pgf@writea=\write3
\r@pgf@reada=\read1
\c@pgf@counta=\count108
\c@pgf@countb=\count109
\c@pgf@countc=\count110
\c@pgf@countd=\count111
\t@pgf@toka=\toks23
\t@pgf@tokb=\toks24
\t@pgf@tokc=\toks25
(c:/TeXLive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg
File: pgf.cfg 2008/05/14 (rcs-revision 1.7)
)
Driver file for pgf: pgfsys-pdftex.def
(c:/TeXLive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-pdftex.def
File: pgfsys-pdftex.def 2014/10/11 (rcs-revision 1.35)
(c:/TeXLive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-commonpdf.
def
File: pgfsys-common-pdf.def 2013/10/10 (rcs-revision 1.13)
)))
(c:/TeXLive/2018/texmfdist/
tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex
File: pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex 2013/09/09 (rcs-revision 1.9)
\pgfsyssoftpath@smallbuffer@items=\count112
\pgfsyssoftpath@bigbuffer@items=\count113
)
(c:/TeXLive/2018/texmfdist/
tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysprotocol.code.tex
File: pgfsysprotocol.code.tex 2006/10/16 (rcs-revision 1.4)
)) (c:/TeXLive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
(c:/TeXLive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 225.
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line
1348.
Package xcolor Info: Model `hsb' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1352.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1364.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line
1366.
(c:/TeXLive/2018/texmfdist/
tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.comparison.co
de.tex)
(c:/TeXLive/2018/texmfdist/
tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.code.tex
)
(c:/TeXLive/2018/texmfdist/
tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round.code.te
x)
(c:/TeXLive/2018/texmfdist/
tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.tex
)
(c:/TeXLive/2018/texmfdist/
tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integerarithm
etics.code.tex))) (c:/TeXLive/2018/texmfdist/
tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat
.code.tex
\c@pgfmathroundto@lastzeros=\count115
)) (c:/TeXLive/2018/texmfdist/
tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepoints.code.te
x
File: pgfcorepoints.code.tex 2013/10/07 (rcs-revision 1.27)
\pgf@picminx=\dimen128
\pgf@picmaxx=\dimen129
\pgf@picminy=\dimen130
\pgf@hbox=\box34
\pgf@layerbox@main=\box35
\pgf@picture@serial@count=\count116
)
(c:/TeXLive/2018/texmfdist/
tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoregraphicstate.code
.tex
File: pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex 2014/11/02 (rcs-revision 1.12)
\pgflinewidth=\dimen146
)
(c:/TeXLive/2018/texmfdist/
tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransformations.c
ode.tex
File: pgfcoretransformations.code.tex 2015/08/07 (rcs-revision 1.20)
\pgf@pt@x=\dimen147
\pgf@pt@y=\dimen148
\pgf@pt@temp=\dimen149
) (c:/TeXLive/2018/texmfdist/
tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorequick.code.tex
File: pgfcorequick.code.tex 2008/10/09 (rcs-revision 1.3)
) (c:/TeXLive/2018/texmfdist/
tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreobjects.code.te
x
File: pgfcoreobjects.code.tex 2006/10/11 (rcs-revision 1.2)
)
(c:/TeXLive/2018/texmfdist/
tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathprocessing.co
de.tex
File: pgfcorepathprocessing.code.tex 2013/09/09 (rcs-revision 1.9)
) (c:/TeXLive/2018/texmfdist/
tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.code.tex
File: pgfcorearrows.code.tex 2015/05/14 (rcs-revision 1.43)
\pgfarrowsep=\dimen150
) (c:/TeXLive/2018/texmfdist/
tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.code.tex
File: pgfcoreshade.code.tex 2013/07/15 (rcs-revision 1.15)
\pgf@max=\dimen151
\pgf@sys@shading@range@num=\count117
) (c:/TeXLive/2018/texmfdist/
tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreimage.code.tex
File: pgfcoreimage.code.tex 2013/07/15 (rcs-revision 1.18)
(c:/TeXLive/2018/texmfdist/
tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreexternal.code.tex
File: pgfcoreexternal.code.tex 2014/07/09 (rcs-revision 1.21)
\pgfexternal@startupbox=\box36
)) (c:/TeXLive/2018/texmfdist/
tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorelayers.code.te
x
File: pgfcorelayers.code.tex 2013/07/18 (rcs-revision 1.7)
)
(c:/TeXLive/2018/texmfdist/
tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransparency.code
.tex
File: pgfcoretransparency.code.tex 2013/09/30 (rcs-revision 1.5)
)
(c:/TeXLive/2018/texmfdist/
tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepatterns.code.tex
File: pgfcorepatterns.code.tex 2013/11/07 (rcs-revision 1.5)
))) (c:/TeXLive/2018/texmfdist/
tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleshapes.code.te
x
File: pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex 2014/03/21 (rcs-revision 1.35)
\pgfnodeparttextbox=\box37
) (c:/TeXLive/2018/texmfdist/
tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleplot.code.tex
File: pgfmoduleplot.code.tex 2015/08/03 (rcs-revision 1.13)
)
(c:/TeXLive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-
0-65.st
y
Package: pgfcomp-version-0-65 2007/07/03 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.7)
\pgf@nodesepstart=\dimen152
\pgf@nodesepend=\dimen153
)
(c:/TeXLive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-
1-18.st
y
Package: pgfcomp-version-1-18 2007/07/23 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.1)
)) (c:/TeXLive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.sty
(c:/TeXLive/2
018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty
(c:/TeXLive/2018/texmf-dist/
tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex)) (c:/TeXLive/2018/texmfdist/
tex/la
tex/pgf/math/pgfmath.sty (c:/TeXLive/2018/texmfdist/
tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfma
th.code.tex)) (c:/TeXLive/2018/texmfdist/
tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code
.tex
Package: pgffor 2013/12/13 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.25)
(c:/TeXLive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex)
\pgffor@iter=\dimen154
\pgffor@skip=\dimen155
\pgffor@stack=\toks29
\pgffor@toks=\toks30
)) (c:/TeXLive/2018/texmfdist/
tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex
Package: tikz 2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.151)
(c:/TeXLive/2018/texmfdist/
tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplothandlers.co
de.tex
File: pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex 2013/08/31 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision
1.20)
\pgf@plot@mark@count=\count118
\pgfplotmarksize=\dimen156
)
\tikz@lastx=\dimen157
\tikz@lasty=\dimen158
\tikz@lastxsaved=\dimen159
\tikz@lastysaved=\dimen160
\tikzleveldistance=\dimen161
\tikzsiblingdistance=\dimen162
\tikz@figbox=\box38
\tikz@figbox@bg=\box39
\tikz@tempbox=\box40
\tikz@tempbox@bg=\box41
\tikztreelevel=\count119
\tikznumberofchildren=\count120
\tikznumberofcurrentchild=\count121
\tikz@fig@count=\count122
(c:/TeXLive/2018/texmfdist/
tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmodulematrix.code.tex
File: pgfmodulematrix.code.tex 2013/09/17 (rcs-revision 1.8)
\pgfmatrixcurrentrow=\count123
\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn=\count124
\pgf@matrix@numberofcolumns=\count125
)
\tikz@expandcount=\count126
(c:/TeXLive/2018/texmfdist/
tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzli
brarytopaths.code.tex
File: tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex 2008/06/17 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.2)
))) (c:/TeXLive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplots.code.tex
(c:/TeXL
ive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplotscore.code.tex
\t@pgfplots@toka=\toks31
\t@pgfplots@tokb=\toks32
\t@pgfplots@tokc=\toks33
\pgfplots@tmpa=\dimen163
\c@pgfplots@coordindex=\count127
\c@pgfplots@scanlineindex=\count128
(c:/TeXLive/2018/texmfdist/
tex/generic/pgfplots/sys/pgfplotssysgeneric.code.te
x)) (c:/TeXLive/2018/texmfdist/
tex/generic/pgfplots/libs/pgfplotslibrary.code.
tex)
(c:/TeXLive/2018/texmfdist/
tex/generic/pgfplots/oldpgfcompatib/pgfplotsoldpgfs
upp_loader.code.tex (c:/TeXLive/2018/texmfdist/
tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgfli
braryfpu.code.tex)
Package pgfplots: loading complementary arithmetics for your pgf
version...
(c:/TeXLive/2018/texmfdist/
tex/generic/pgfplots/oldpgfcompatib/pgfplotsoldpgfs
upp_pgflibraryfpu.code.tex)
(c:/TeXLive/2018/texmfdist/
tex/generic/pgfplots/oldpgfcompatib/pgfplotsoldpgfs
upp_pgfmathfloat.code.tex
\c@pgfmathroundto@lastzeros=\count129
)
(c:/TeXLive/2018/texmfdist/
tex/generic/pgfplots/oldpgfcompatib/pgfplotsoldpgfs
upp_leq.code.tex)) (c:/TeXLive/2018/texmfdist/
tex/generic/pgfplots/util/pgfplo
tsutil.code.tex
c:/TeXLive/2018/texmfdist/
tex/generic/pgfplots/liststructure/pgfplotsliststru
cture.code.tex)
(c:/TeXLive/2018/texmfdist/
tex/generic/pgfplots/liststructure/pgfplotsliststru
ctureext.code.tex)
(c:/TeXLive/2018/texmfdist/
tex/generic/pgfplots/liststructure/pgfplotsarray.co
de.tex
\c@pgfplotsarray@tmp=\count130
)
(c:/TeXLive/2018/texmfdist/
tex/generic/pgfplots/liststructure/pgfplotsmatrix.c
ode.tex)
(c:/TeXLive/2018/texmfdist/
tex/generic/pgfplots/numtable/pgfplotstableshared.c
ode.tex
\c@pgfplotstable@counta=\count131
\t@pgfplotstable@a=\toks34
)
(c:/TeXLive/2018/texmfdist/
tex/generic/pgfplots/liststructure/pgfplotsdeque.co
de.tex) (c:/TeXLive/2018/texmfdist/
tex/generic/pgfplots/util/pgfplotsbinary.co
de.tex
(c:/TeXLive/2018/texmfdist/
tex/generic/pgfplots/util/pgfplotsbinary.data.code.
tex))
(c:/TeXLive/2018/texmfdist/
tex/generic/pgfplots/util/pgfplotsutil.verb.code.te
x)
(c:/TeXLive/2018/texmfdist/
tex/generic/pgfplots/libs/pgflibrarypgfplots.surfsh
ading.code.tex
\c@pgfplotslibrarysurf@no=\count132
(c:/TeXLive/2018/texmfdist/
tex/generic/pgfplots/sys/pgflibrarypgfplots.surfsha
ding.pgfsys-pdftex.def)))
(c:/TeXLive/2018/texmfdist/
tex/generic/pgfplots/util/pgfplotscolormap.code.tex
(c:/TeXLive/2018/texmfdist/
tex/generic/pgfplots/util/pgfplotscolor.code.tex))
(c:/TeXLive/2018/texmfdist/
tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplotsstackedplots.code.tex)
(c:/TeXLive/2018/texmfdist/
tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplotsplothandlers.code.tex
(c:/TeXLive/2018/texmfdist/
tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplotsmeshplothandler.code.t
ex
(c:/TeXLive/2018/texmfdist/
tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplotsmeshplotimage.code.tex
))) (c:/TeXLive/2018/texmfdist/
tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplots.scaling.code.tex)
(c:/TeXLive/2018/texmfdist/
tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplotscoordprocessing.code.t
ex) (c:/TeXLive/2018/texmfdist/
tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplots.errorbars.code.te
x) (c:/TeXLive/2018/texmfdist/
tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplots.markers.code.tex)
(c:/TeXLive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplotsticks.code.tex)
(c:/Te
XLive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplots.paths.code.tex)
(c:/TeXLive/2018/texmfdist/
tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzli
brarydecorations.code.tex
(c:/TeXLive/2018/texmfdist/
tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduledecorations.code.t
ex
\pgfdecoratedcompleteddistance=\dimen164
\pgfdecoratedremainingdistance=\dimen165
\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentcompleteddistance=\dimen166
\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentremainingdistance=\dimen167
\pgf@decorate@distancetomove=\dimen168
\pgf@decorate@repeatstate=\count133
\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude=\dimen169
\pgfdecorationsegmentlength=\dimen170
)
\tikz@lib@dec@box=\box42
)
(c:/TeXLive/2018/texmfdist/
tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzli
brarydecorations.pathmorphing.code.tex
(c:/TeXLive/2018/texmfdist/
tex/generic/pgf/libraries/decorations/pgflibrarydec
orations.pathmorphing.code.tex))
(c:/TeXLive/2018/texmfdist/
tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzli
brarydecorations.pathreplacing.code.tex
(c:/TeXLive/2018/texmfdist/
tex/generic/pgf/libraries/decorations/pgflibrarydec
orations.pathreplacing.code.tex))
\pgfplots@numplots=\count134
\pgfplots@xmin@reg=\dimen171
\pgfplots@xmax@reg=\dimen172
\pgfplots@ymin@reg=\dimen173
\pgfplots@ymax@reg=\dimen174
\pgfplots@zmin@reg=\dimen175
\pgfplots@zmax@reg=\dimen176
)
(c:/TeXLive/2018/texmfdist/
tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzli
braryplotmarks.code.tex
File: tikzlibraryplotmarks.code.tex 2008/01/09 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.1)
(c:/TeXLive/2018/texmfdist/
tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplotmarks.code.
tex
File: pgflibraryplotmarks.code.tex 2015/08/03 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.14)
))) (c:/TeXLive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
Package: amsmath 2017/09/02 v2.17a AMS math features
\@mathmargin=\skip45
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(c:/TeXLive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
Package: amstext 2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text
(c:/TeXLive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
\@emptytoks=\toks35
\ex@=\dimen177
)) (c:/TeXLive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
\pmbraise@=\dimen178
) (c:/TeXLive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty
Package: amsopn 2016/03/08 v2.02 operator names
)
\inf@bad=\count135
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 213.
\uproot@=\count136
\leftroot@=\count137
LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 375.
\classnum@=\count138
\DOTSCASE@=\count139
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 472.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 475.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 596.
\Mathstrutbox@=\box43
\strutbox@=\box44
\big@size=\dimen179
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 712.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 713.
Package amsmath Warning: Unable to redefine math accent \vec.
\macc@depth=\count140
\c@MaxMatrixCols=\count141
\dotsspace@=\muskip10
\c@parentequation=\count142
\dspbrk@lvl=\count143
\tag@help=\toks36
\row@=\count144
\column@=\count145
\maxfields@=\count146
\andhelp@=\toks37
\eqnshift@=\dimen180
\alignsep@=\dimen181
\tagshift@=\dimen182
\tagwidth@=\dimen183
\totwidth@=\dimen184
\lineht@=\dimen185
\@envbody=\toks38
\multlinegap=\skip46
\multlinetaggap=\skip47
\mathdisplay@stack=\toks39
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2817.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2818.
) (c:/TeXLive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mathtools/mathtools.sty
Package: mathtools 2018/01/08 v1.21 mathematical typesetting tools
(c:/TeXLive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty
Package: calc 2017/05/25 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
\calc@Acount=\count147
\calc@Bcount=\count148
\calc@Adimen=\dimen186
\calc@Bdimen=\dimen187
\calc@Askip=\skip48
\calc@Bskip=\skip49
LaTeX Info: Redefining \setlength on input line 80.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \addtolength on input line 81.
\calc@Ccount=\count149
\calc@Cskip=\skip50
) (c:/TeXLive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mathtools/mhsetup.sty
Package: mhsetup 2017/03/31 v1.3 programming setup (MH)
)
LaTeX Info: Thecontrolsequence`\('isalreadyrobust on input line 129.
LaTeX Info: Thecontrolsequence`\)'isalreadyrobust on input line 129.
LaTeX Info: Thecontrolsequence`\['isalreadyrobust on input line 129.
LaTeX Info: Thecontrolsequence`\]'isalreadyrobust on input line 129.
\g_MT_multlinerow_int=\count150
\l_MT_multwidth_dim=\dimen188
\origjot=\skip51
\l_MT_shortvdotswithinadjustabove_dim=\dimen189
\l_MT_shortvdotswithinadjustbelow_dim=\dimen190
\l_MT_above_intertext_sep=\dimen191
\l_MT_below_intertext_sep=\dimen192
\l_MT_above_shortintertext_sep=\dimen193
\l_MT_below_shortintertext_sep=\dimen194
) (c:/TeXLive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty
Package: amssymb 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols
(c:/TeXLive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty
Package: amsfonts 2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
\symAMSa=\mathgroup4
\symAMSb=\mathgroup5
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting math alphabet `\mathfrak' in version
`bold'
(Font) U/euf/m/n --> U/euf/b/n on input line 106.
)) (c:/TeXLive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/polyglossia.sty
Package: polyglossia 2018/04/07 v1.43 Alternative to Babel for XeLaTeX
and LuaL
aTeX
(c:/TeXLive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2018/02/11 v2.5e e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count151
) (c:/TeXLive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/makecmds/makecmds.sty
Package: makecmds 2009/09/03 v1.0a extra command making commands
) (c:/TeXLive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
Package: xkeyval 2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)
(c:/TeXLive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(c:/TeXLive/2018/te
xmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
\XKV@toks=\toks40
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks41
)
\XKV@depth=\count152
File: xkeyval.tex 2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
)) (c:/TeXLive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
(c:/TeXLive/2018
/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
(c:/TeXLive/2018/texmf-dist/
tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
Package: expl3 2018-06-14 L3 programming layer (loader)
(c:/TeXLive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.tex
Package: expl3 2018-06-14 L3 programming layer (code)
\c_max_int=\count153
\l_tmpa_int=\count154
\l_tmpb_int=\count155
\g_tmpa_int=\count156
\g_tmpb_int=\count157
\g__kernel_prg_map_int=\count158
\c_log_iow=\count159
\l_iow_line_count_int=\count160
\l__iow_line_target_int=\count161
\l__iow_one_indent_int=\count162
\l__iow_indent_int=\count163
\c_zero_dim=\dimen195
\c_max_dim=\dimen196
\l_tmpa_dim=\dimen197
\l_tmpb_dim=\dimen198
\g_tmpa_dim=\dimen199
\g_tmpb_dim=\dimen256
\c_zero_skip=\skip52
\c_max_skip=\skip53
\l_tmpa_skip=\skip54
\l_tmpb_skip=\skip55
\g_tmpa_skip=\skip56
\g_tmpb_skip=\skip57
\c_zero_muskip=\muskip11
\c_max_muskip=\muskip12
\l_tmpa_muskip=\muskip13
\l_tmpb_muskip=\muskip14
\g_tmpa_muskip=\muskip15
\g_tmpb_muskip=\muskip16
\l_keys_choice_int=\count164
\l__intarray_loop_int=\count165
\c__intarray_sp_dim=\dimen257
\g__intarray_font_int=\count166
\c__fp_leading_shift_int=\count167
\c__fp_middle_shift_int=\count168
\c__fp_trailing_shift_int=\count169
\c__fp_big_leading_shift_int=\count170
\c__fp_big_middle_shift_int=\count171
\c__fp_big_trailing_shift_int=\count172
\c__fp_Bigg_leading_shift_int=\count173
\c__fp_Bigg_middle_shift_int=\count174
\c__fp_Bigg_trailing_shift_int=\count175
\c__kernel_randint_max_int=\count176
\g__fp_array_int=\count177
\l__fp_array_loop_int=\count178
\l__sort_length_int=\count179
\l__sort_min_int=\count180
\l__sort_top_int=\count181
\l__sort_max_int=\count182
\l__sort_true_max_int=\count183
\l__sort_block_int=\count184
\l__sort_begin_int=\count185
\l__sort_end_int=\count186
\l__sort_A_int=\count187
\l__sort_B_int=\count188
\l__sort_C_int=\count189
\l__tl_analysis_normal_int=\count190
\l__tl_analysis_index_int=\count191
\l__tl_analysis_nesting_int=\count192
\l__tl_analysis_type_int=\count193
\l__regex_internal_a_int=\count194
\l__regex_internal_b_int=\count195
\l__regex_internal_c_int=\count196
\l__regex_balance_int=\count197
\l__regex_group_level_int=\count198
\l__regex_mode_int=\count199
\c__regex_cs_in_class_mode_int=\count266
\c__regex_cs_mode_int=\count267
\l__regex_catcodes_int=\count268
\l__regex_default_catcodes_int=\count269
\c__regex_catcode_D_int=\count270
\c__regex_catcode_S_int=\count271
\c__regex_catcode_L_int=\count272
\c__regex_catcode_O_int=\count273
\c__regex_catcode_A_int=\count274
\c__regex_all_catcodes_int=\count275
\l__regex_show_lines_int=\count276
\l__regex_min_state_int=\count277
\l__regex_max_state_int=\count278
\l__regex_left_state_int=\count279
\l__regex_right_state_int=\count280
\l__regex_capturing_group_int=\count281
\l__regex_min_pos_int=\count282
\l__regex_max_pos_int=\count283
\l__regex_curr_pos_int=\count284
\l__regex_start_pos_int=\count285
\l__regex_success_pos_int=\count286
\l__regex_curr_char_int=\count287
\l__regex_curr_catcode_int=\count288
\l__regex_last_char_int=\count289
\l__regex_case_changed_char_int=\count290
\l__regex_curr_state_int=\count291
\l__regex_step_int=\count292
\l__regex_min_active_int=\count293
\l__regex_max_active_int=\count294
\l__regex_replacement_csnames_int=\count295
\l__regex_match_count_int=\count296
\l__regex_min_submatch_int=\count297
\l__regex_submatch_int=\count298
\l__regex_zeroth_submatch_int=\count299
\g__regex_trace_regex_int=\count300
\c_empty_box=\box45
\l_tmpa_box=\box46
\l_tmpb_box=\box47
\g_tmpa_box=\box48
\g_tmpb_box=\box49
\l__box_top_dim=\dimen258
\l__box_bottom_dim=\dimen259
\l__box_left_dim=\dimen260
\l__box_right_dim=\dimen261
\l__box_top_new_dim=\dimen262
\l__box_bottom_new_dim=\dimen263
\l__box_left_new_dim=\dimen264
\l__box_right_new_dim=\dimen265
\l__box_internal_box=\box50
\l__coffin_internal_box=\box51
\l__coffin_internal_dim=\dimen266
\l__coffin_offset_x_dim=\dimen267
\l__coffin_offset_y_dim=\dimen268
\l__coffin_x_dim=\dimen269
\l__coffin_y_dim=\dimen270
\l__coffin_x_prime_dim=\dimen271
\l__coffin_y_prime_dim=\dimen272
\c_empty_coffin=\box52
\l__coffin_aligned_coffin=\box53
\l__coffin_aligned_internal_coffin=\box54
\l_tmpa_coffin=\box55
\l_tmpb_coffin=\box56
\l__coffin_display_coffin=\box57
\l__coffin_display_coord_coffin=\box58
\l__coffin_display_pole_coffin=\box59
\l__coffin_display_offset_dim=\dimen273
\l__coffin_display_x_dim=\dimen274
\l__coffin_display_y_dim=\dimen275
\g__file_internal_ior=\read2
\l__coffin_bounding_shift_dim=\dimen276
\l__coffin_left_corner_dim=\dimen277
\l__coffin_right_corner_dim=\dimen278
\l__coffin_bottom_corner_dim=\dimen279
\l__coffin_top_corner_dim=\dimen280
\l__coffin_scaled_total_height_dim=\dimen281
\l__coffin_scaled_width_dim=\dimen282
\l__seq_internal_a_int=\count301
\l__seq_internal_b_int=\count302
) (c:/TeXLive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3pdfmode.def
File: l3pdfmode.def 2018-06-14 v L3 Experimental driver: PDF mode
\l__driver_color_stack_int=\count303
))
Package: xparse 2018-05-12 L3 Experimental document command parser
\l__xparse_current_arg_int=\count304
\g__xparse_grabber_int=\count305
\l__xparse_m_args_int=\count306
\l__xparse_mandatory_args_int=\count307
\l__xparse_v_nesting_int=\count308
)
Package: fontspec 2017/11/09 v2.6g Font selection for XeLaTeX and
LuaLaTeX
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! Fatal fontspec error: "cannot-use-pdftex"
!
! The fontspec package requires either XeTeX or LuaTeX.
!
! You must change your typesetting engine to, e.g., "xelatex" or
! "lualatex"instead of "latex" or "pdflatex".
!
! See the fontspec documentation for further information.
!
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................
l.44 \msg_fatal:nn {fontspec} {cannot-use-pdftex}
|'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
| This is a fatal error: LaTeX will abort.
|...............................................
) ) )
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
32352 strings out of 492646
770436 string characters out of 6133325
875798 words of memory out of 5000000
35863 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
532338 words of font info for 24 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
62i,1n,96p,828b,609s stack positions out of
5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
No pages of output.
PDF statistics:
3 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: your title asks about xelatex but you are showing a log from pdflatex

Comment: also "not built properly" does not allow anyone to help you. What error did you get, what does your source look like, did you intend the source to be used with xelatex or pdflatex? You need to post a _question_ not just post a log file.

Comment: but given that your log says `! You must change your typesetting engine to, e.g., "xelatex" `  then you should use xelatex not pdflatex

Comment: This is the pdf generated from editorial manager. There is a option in the em to compile the xelatex file: %!TEX TS-program = xelatex. I added that line. I checked with another simple file. It works. But it is not working for journal file.

Comment: like most people here I have no idea about the "editorial manager" that you are using but that log is from pdflatex not xelatex. The comment `%!TEX TS-program = xelatex.` is a comment by default it does nothing. _some_ editors will see that comment and choose to use xelatex but there is no reason to suppose that other systems will do that. You only need to look at the first line `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018/W32TeX)`

Comment: Tq. But I compiled another file. It performs xelatex compiling.

Comment: perhaps you made an error in the comment, how are we to know? You have shown no input nor said what system you are using, all you have shown is a log from pdflatex of an unseen document so the only answer that we can give is use xelatex not pdflatex.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Running my file in Texstudio.Here also in my log file, i could see the same messages shown in em.  This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999991 (MiKTeX 2.9.7250 64-bit) (preloaded format=xelatex 2019.11.16)  19 MAY 2020 16:44
entering extended mode
**./ManuscriptFinal3.tex
(ManuscriptFinal3.tex
LaTeX2e <2019-10-01> patch level 3
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\fix-cm.sty"
Package: fix-cm 2015/01/14 v1.1t fixes to LaTeX

Comment: I don't know what answer you want. That is a xelatex log file, the log in your question is from pdflatex